# Apache SSL certificate installation for beginner

Tags: apache, ssl

I just started to learn programming and tried to install SSL on my site.

I used a 90-day free trial SSL from Comodo and it worked well.

I purchased a new SSL from Comodo and generated CSR on the server (on my putty terminal)

My site is a Wordpress run by Bitnami and AWS.

Error message is that my site name is mismatched.

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.cheeselab.co.kr#whyNotTrusted

How could I solve this problem? I tried to re-install it from the scratch but I don't know what I have to do.

Below codes are what I did

```
sudo openssl genrsa -out /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key 204

sudo openssl req -new -key /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key -out /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/cert.csr

sudo nano /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/cert.csr

sudo nano /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/cert2.crt 

sudo nano /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf
```

renamed the file from server.crt to cert2.crt

(above codes worked well)

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

but error message with above code as below

Invalid command 'sudo', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration apache config test fails, aborting Monitored apache

Comment: You've not installed the certificate correctly and thus it does not show the certificate you wanted to install but some default certificate. Since you don't describe how exactly you've tried to install the certificate it is unknown what you did wrong.

Comment: Hello, Steffen.

I am not a engineer so not good at solving a problem.